# У меня есть задача, которую я хочу реализовать в PyQt5

Tags: pyqt5, qt-designer

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я новичок в pyqt5
в моем проекте я хочу реализовать это окно, у меня есть база данных с книгами и тд. После ввода автора в lineedit и нажатия на кнопку поиск, должны создаваться кнопки с произведениями данного автора. Книг автора может быть бесконечное количество. Я не знаю как создавать кнопки с названиями произведения, точнее через что это можно реализовать, и куда их добавлять(list view, а может что то другое) Помогите пожалуйста

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: я спрашиваю, как реализовать бесконечное количество кнопок с названиями книг данного автора, при нажатии на кнопку с названием, я буду открывать новое окно с информацией о ней. У меня есть бд с названиями книг и авторами и тд. при выборе автора в combo box, я буду считывать имя автора, и выдавать кнопки с названиями книг. Я не знаю куда их поместить и как их сделать

Comment: на фотографии видно, как должны выдаваться кнопки

Comment: Aydar опубликуйте ваш модуль `.ui` и приведите пример данных (несколько строк), которые вы получаете из БД.